# LoadRunner testing over different domains

Tags: cross-domain, loadrunner

I have been requested to use LoadRunner to do load testing.  While my LR servers are all physical servers, i will need to test a system that's not only on VM's, but i'll need to access through a VDI AND the system under test is in a completely different secure domain (diff OU's).  This makes me believe there is going to be a large disparity and skewed performance results with all of the tokens and authentication that will have to happen.  How can I measure this gap if at all?

Comment: Since this is not exactly a code question, I suggest you ask this question on the LoadRunner community forum or contact our COST team (they are reading the forum so if you post there you are covered)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to assess performance for the application or the VDI terminal interface?   This is an important consideration as to your path.

It does not matter if your target for AUT is on VM or Physical for your load generators.  This does impact your monitoring strategy to collect monitoring stats for from the target AUT hypervisor rather than from the VM Guest OS.

You can have load generators and monitors behind a firewall.  Take a look at the documentation for a path on this